# Shellwords.shellescape implementation for Ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, escaping, sh

While the build of 1.8.7 I have seems to have a backported version of `Shellwords::shellescape`, I know that method is a 1.9 feature and definitely isn't supported in earlier versions of 1.8.  Does anyone know where I can find, either in Gem form or just as a snippet, a robust standalone implementation of Bourne-shell command escaping for Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wound up going with the [Escape](http://www.a-k-r.org/escape/) gem, which has the additional feature of using quotes by default, and only backslash-escaping when necessary.

Answer (score 9):

You might as well just copy what you want from [shellwords.rb](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/trunk/lib/shellwords.rb) in the trunk of Ruby's subversion repository (which is [GPLv2](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/trunk/COPYING)'d):

```
  def shellescape(str)
    # An empty argument will be skipped, so return empty quotes.
    return "''" if str.empty?

    str = str.dup

    # Process as a single byte sequence because not all shell
    # implementations are multibyte aware.
    str.gsub!(/([^A-Za-z0-9_\-.,:\/@\n])/n, "\\\\\\1")

    # A LF cannot be escaped with a backslash because a backslash + LF
    # combo is regarded as line continuation and simply ignored.
    str.gsub!(/\n/, "'\n'")

    return str
  end
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wound up going with the Escape gem (see my answer); but this is definitely a viable option.  BTW, Ruby is dual licensed according to the file you linked.

Comment: With regards to licensing, a snippet this small is fair use (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) anyway. As the FSF states (http://www.gnu.org/prep/maintain/maintain.html#Legally-Significant): "just a few lines (less than 15 or so) is not legally significant for copyright."