# How to hide password input from terminal in ruby script

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. I need to receive password as an input through `gets` command.

How do I hide the password input typed in the terminal, during `gets` call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read a password from the command line in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133719/how-can-i-read-a-password-from-the-command-line-in-ruby)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Best method from @eclectic923's answer:

```ruby
require 'io/console'
password = STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
```

For 1.9.3 (and above), this requires you adding `require 'io/console'` to your code.

#### Original Answer:

Ruby "[Password](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/ruby-password/classes/Password.html)" is another alternative.

Comment: This answer should be deprecated in favour of @eclectic923 core ruby solution.

Answer (score 185):

One can also use core ruby.

```
$ ri IO.noecho

 (from ruby core)
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   io.noecho {|io| }
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Yields self with disabling echo back.

   STDIN.noecho(&:gets)

 will read and return a line without echo back.
```

For 1.9.3 (and above), this requires you adding `require 'io/console'` to your code.

```
require 'io/console'
text = STDIN.noecho(&:gets)
```

Comment: For 1.9.3, this requires you adding `require 'io/console'` to your code. Way better than any gem option usually.

Comment: I cannot +1 this answer enough. Beats having to include extra gems any day!

Comment: don't forget to .chomp your input! pass = STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp

Comment: How do you get this to work in Cygwin? `tmp.rb:2:in 'noecho': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
        from tmp.rb:2:in <main>`

Answer (score 31):

There is a library called [highline](http://highline.rubyforge.org/) which works like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'highline/import'

password = ask("Enter password: ") { |q| q.echo = false }
# do stuff with password
```

Answer (score 19):

Starting from Ruby version 2.3.0 you can use the `IO#getpass` method like this:

```
require 'io/console'
password = STDIN.getpass("Password:")
```

See the [getpass](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-getpass) method in the Standard Library Documentation.

Comment: How to echo a specific character like * using getpass?

Comment: $stdin.getpass still writes a newline to $stdout

Comment: `STDIN.getpass.chomp` solves that issue @ShadSterling

Comment: Oh, and while it may print a newline to STDOUT, `getpass` calls `chomp!` internally on the input string so it's a better tool than other answers these days. See [docs](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/io#method-i-getpass) for reference: 
`The newline character that terminates the read line is removed from the returned string, see String#chomp!.`

Answer (score 16):

As the others mention, you can use [`IO#noecho`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-noecho) for Ruby >= 1.9. If you'd like support for 1.8, you can shell out to the [`read`](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html) builtin shell function:

```
begin
  require 'io/console'
rescue LoadError
end

if STDIN.respond_to?(:noecho)
  def get_password(prompt="Password: ")
    print prompt
    STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
  end
else
  def get_password(prompt="Password: ")
    `read -s -p "#{prompt}" password; echo $password`.chomp
  end
end
```

Now getting a password is as easy as:

```
@password = get_password("Enter your password here: ")
```

---

**Note:** In the implementation using `read` above, you'll run into trouble if you (or some other client of `get_password`) passes along special shell characters in the prompt (e.g. `$`/`"`/`'`/etc). Ideally, you should escape the prompt string before passing it along to the shell. Unfortunately, [`Shellwords`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) isn't available in Ruby 1.8. Fortunately, it's easy to [backport the relevant bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306680/shellwords-shellescape-implementation-for-ruby-1-8#1320011) yourself (specifically [`shellescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-shellescape)). With that, you can make this slight modification:

```
  def get_password(prompt="Password: ")
    `read -s -p #{Shellwords.shellescape(prompt)} password; echo $password`.chomp
  end
```

---

I mentioned a couple problems with the use of `read -s -p` in a comment below:

> Well, the 1.8 case is a little janky; it doesn't allow for
>   backslashes, unless you hit backslash twice: "The backslash character
>   `\' may be used to remove any special meaning for the next character
>   read and for line continuation." Also: "The characters in the value of
>   the IFS variable are used to split the line into words. " This should
>   probably be fine for most little scripts, but you'd probably want
>   something more robust for larger applications.

We can fix some of those problems by rolling up our sleeves and doing this the hard with [`stty(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty). An outline of what we need to do:

- Store the current terminal settings
- Turn of echoing
- Print the prompt & get user input
- Restore the terminal settings

We must also take care to restore the terminal settings when interrupted by signals and/or exceptions. The following code will properly handle job control signals (SIGINT/SIGTSTP/SIGCONT) while still playing nicely with any present signal handlers:

```
require 'shellwords'
def get_password(prompt="Password: ")
  new_sigint = new_sigtstp = new_sigcont = nil
  old_sigint = old_sigtstp = old_sigcont = nil

  # save the current terminal configuration
  term = `stty -g`.chomp
  # turn of character echo
  `stty -echo`

  new_sigint = Proc.new do
    `stty #{term.shellescape}`
    trap("SIGINT",  old_sigint)
    Process.kill("SIGINT", Process.pid)
  end

  new_sigtstp = Proc.new do
    `stty #{term.shellescape}`
    trap("SIGCONT", new_sigcont)
    trap("SIGTSTP", old_sigtstp)
    Process.kill("SIGTSTP", Process.pid)
  end

  new_sigcont = Proc.new do
    `stty -echo`
    trap("SIGCONT", old_sigcont)
    trap("SIGTSTP", new_sigtstp)
    Process.kill("SIGCONT", Process.pid)
  end

  # set all signal handlers
  old_sigint  = trap("SIGINT",  new_sigint)  || "DEFAULT"
  old_sigtstp = trap("SIGTSTP", new_sigtstp) || "DEFAULT"
  old_sigcont = trap("SIGCONT", new_sigcont) || "DEFAULT"

  print prompt
  password = STDIN.gets.chomp
  puts

  password
ensure
  # restore term and handlers
  `stty #{term.shellescape}`

  trap("SIGINT",  old_sigint)
  trap("SIGTSTP", old_sigtstp)
  trap("SIGCONT", old_sigcont)
end
```

Comment: Well, the 1.8 case is a little janky; it doesn't allow for backslashes, unless you hit backslash twice: "The backslash character `\' may be used to remove any special meaning for the next character read and for line continuation." Also: "The characters in the value of the IFS variable are used to split the line into words. " This should probably be fine for most little scripts, but you'd probably want something more robust for larger applications.

Answer (score 5):

For ruby version 1.8 (or Ruby < 1.9) I used [read](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html) shell builtin as mentioned by @Charles.

Putting the code thats just enough to prompt for user name & password, where user name will be echoed to screen while typing in however password typed in would be silent.

```
 userid = `read -p "User Name: " uid; echo $uid`.chomp
 passwd = `read -s -p "Password: " password; echo $password`.chomp
```