# Ruby Gem "password" Does Not Seem To Install Properly

Tags: ruby, rubygems, passwords

I am trying to obscure the user input (for example, when inputting a password) for a ruby script.  I've tried using both the 'password' gem and 'highline/import' gem, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338889/how-to-hide-password-input-from-terminal-in-ruby-script) stack overflow article.  However, I seems to be having some issues getting the gems to work.  When my script is simply:

```
require 'password'
require 'rubygems'
require 'activesupport'
```

it outputs the following errors.

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop>ruby test.rb
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
activesupport (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/password-1.3/lib/password.rb:1:
in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure that 'activesupport' is necessary; I added it because of the first error line and it hasn't seemed to help.  I tried looking at the rdoc information found in the RubyGems Documentation Server and looking up each of the individual lines, but still cannot quite grasp what the problem is.  I am using Ruby 1.9.2p180 on a Windows environment.  Any insight would be much appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

**EDIT --**
After following the advice of Casper, and installing the highline/import gem (`gem install highline`), I was able to find the following solution to my ultimate goal of obscuring password input:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'highline/import'

username = ask("Enter username:  ") { |x| x.echo = true }
password = ask("Enter password:  ") { |x| x.echo = "*" } #assign false to echo nothing
```

which produces the following:

```
Enter username: Joe
Enter password: *********
```

Thanks Casper!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load `rubygems` **before** you try to load any other gem files. `rubygems` is what enables your Ruby programs to load other gems with `require`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'password'
require 'activesupport'
```

Before you can use the password gem however you need to install it:

```
gem install ruby-password
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I reorganized the gems as you suggested; however, I cannot install ruby-password on either my Windows environment or a Linux VM.  They consistently complain about: `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`  I tried installing the Windows DevKit, but it does not seem to have installed correctly.  And the Devkit is meant to produce a 'Sane' environment on Windows (include gcc, make, sh) from what I've gathered, so it should not impact Linux.  So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong--I cant get ruby-password to install.

Comment: Hmm..looks password needs something called `cracklib` to be installed before you install. You have two options: a) look at the code in the password gem and extract the part you need to your own project (you don't need the cracklib part, only the password ask system), or b) use the `highline` gem instead.