# In Ruby, how to ask the terminal not to echo key presses?

Tags: ruby, keypress

In Ruby, how can I ask the terminal not to echo key presses?

Same as when SSH asks for a password. Keys are typed but nothing would show on the terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide password input from terminal in ruby script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338889/how-to-hide-password-input-from-terminal-in-ruby-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cann also use stty to disable echo :

```
def getch
  %x[stty -echo raw]
  c = $stdin.getc
  %x[stty echo -raw]
  c
end
```

And in 1.9.3, the io/console library will allow you to do it in a more portable way:

```
require 'io/console'
$stdin.getch # does the same thing as above :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [highline gem](http://highline.rubyforge.org/) - the `HighLine::Question` class has a parameter to control the echo of the input text.