# Hide user input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, obfuscation

I'm looking to read in data from the user, however, I do not want the input to show directly on the screen. Rather, I'd like to leave it blank or better yet, obfuscate characters to be input with an astericks.

For example:

```
print "Password: "
pass = STDIN.gets.chomp
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide password input from terminal in ruby script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338889/how-to-hide-password-input-from-terminal-in-ruby-script)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using at least ruby 1.9, you can use the `noecho` method on `IO`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/io/console/rdoc/IO.html#method-i-noecho

So:

```
require 'io/console'
print "Password: "
STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp
```

This will not obfuscate the characters, but will simply leave the input terminal blank.

Comment: I found the highline gem provided more options. 
require 'highline/import'

passowrd = ask("Password: ") { |q| q.echo="*")

This will replace the users input with *