# Send string to pipe without echoing to terminal

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a simple wrapper for the command line tool pwsafe. I am doing something like this:

```
def fetch_app_password
  master_password = driver.get # this reliably fetches the correct master password
  open( "| pwsafe", 'r+' ) do |pwsafe-pipe|
    pwsafe_pipe.write(master_password + "\n")
    app_password = pwsafe_pipe.read()
    return app_password
  end
  raise 'an error occurred'
end
```

This code is correct in that it fetches the correct application password. The trouble is that you can see the exchange on the terminal:

```
enter passphrase for /home/user/pwsafe.dat: $oup3rSeKr!T
```

This is not so secure against shoulder surfers. I'd like to prevent the password being sent to the pipe from ending up on my terminal in cleartext. I would appreciate suggestions.

Update: some code I've tried

```
def fetch_app_password
  master_password = driver.get
  open( "| pwsafe", 'r+' ).noecho do |pwsafe-pipe|
    pwsafe_pipe.write(master_password + "\n")
    app_password = pwsafe_pipe.read()
    return app_password
  end
  raise 'an error occurred'
end

def fetch_app_password
  master_password = driver.get
  open3.Popen("pwsafe") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, ignored|
    stdin.noecho { |stdin| stdin.write( master_password + "\n") }
    app_password = stdout.noecho { |stdout| stdout.readline() }
    return app_password
  end
  raise 'an error occurred'
end
```

Both of those implementtions raise the exception `inappropriate ioctl for device (errno::NOTTY)` when I try to call `noecho`. Calling `noecho` on the outside console has no effect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide password input from terminal in ruby script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338889/how-to-hide-password-input-from-terminal-in-ruby-script)

Comment: Not a duplicate; that question deals with reading passwords from `stdin`, not writing them to a pipe. I'll update with some similar code that is also not working.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Using open3 _should_ catch all output from the process. If you're still seeing output from pwsafe on the command line, then it is using some weird workaround to write to the console without using the stdout or stderr streams.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies with pwsafe itself. To demonstrate why, I made a little test script with Ruby that reads stdin and writes to both stdout and stderr:

```
# streams.rb
STDERR.print "Input text to reverse: "
STDOUT.puts STDIN.read.reverse
```

Then I ran it using `open3`

```
require 'open3'
Open3.popen3('./streams.rb') do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thr|
  stdin.write("Super secret password")
  stdin.close

  puts "OUT: #{stdout.read}"
  puts "ERR: #{stderr.read}"
end
```

And the only output that appears are the two `puts`:

```
OUT: drowssap terces repuS
ERR: Input text to reverse:
```

If your script is still outputting other stuff to the command line, either you aren't showing us all the relevant code or the problem lies entirely outside Ruby.

Comment: Wow. Good catch. I guess I'll have to dig into pwsafe to see whether it does anything weird when receiving input. I'm not totally sold on it being a pwsafe issue though, since pwsafe does not echo stdin to when receiving input from my keyboard. I'll do some more testing.

Comment: I replicated your streams.rb program in C++ (which pwsafe is written in) and got the same behavior as streams.rb; it's probably the case that `pwsafe` is doing something weird.