# Ruby how to mask user input using a specific character?

Tags: ruby

I have a method to ask user the password like this:

```rb
def ask_user_password
  puts 'Enter your password'
  print '> '
  STDIN.getpass
end
```

Once I'm using STDIN.getpass, it doesn't display the user input.

But instead, I want to print the * character for every character the user enters.
Eg: User input: **123456**

Now I have

```
Enter your password
>
```

What I want

```
Enter your password
> ******
```

Comment: Do any of the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338889/how-to-hide-password-input-from-terminal-in-ruby-script help?

Comment: This answer does exactly what i'm doing... Hiding instead of masking ;)

Comment: Very smart people have concluded that it is better to echo nothing for secure input than it is to echo a mask for each character, so I would ask you why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Simple, this code is for an small application for myself only with zero distribution intention. So being the single user is nice to have this usability feature to help myself avoid miss my password. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this gem: [highline](https://github.com/JEG2/highline). And your code might be like this:

```
require 'highline/import'

def ask_user_password
  puts 'Enter your password'
  ask("> ") { |q| q.echo =  '*' }
end
```

If you dont want to echo anything, just change the echo to false.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!